# performance tuning of ASP.NET webpage

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms, performance

One of my ASP.NET webpage is taking more time to load and I want to optimize its performance. During debugging, I am not able to find where it is taking more time. It looks all fine. Is there any special way or any option with Visual Studio 2008 for performance tuning?

Answer (score 2):

Debugging might be slow. If you find out that your application is slow while running in `Release` mode then there might be a problem with your application that you will need to pinpoint. You could read on [how to improve the performance of your ASP.NET application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx) and [10 tips for writing high performance web applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx). You could also use a [profiler](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=.net+profiler&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7db4f7af4a13aa89).

Answer (score 2):

You can use YSlow to analyze client side for potential problems and [Performance testing tool for code analysis on .NET applications](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/) for server side problems.